# How to create an ouput text box from a select list in html

Tags: javascript, html, dom

This code works to output a box with one of my select options, but I am trying to make it work for multiple items.

The idea is that you would be able to select multiple items, and once you press the 'add item to your cart' button, it would be put below the select box in a text box.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="hello.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h5>Grocery Categories</h5>
    <select name="products" size="6" multiple>
      <option id="bread">Bread</option>
      <option id="dairy">Dairy</option>
      <option id="frozen">Frozen</option>
      <option id="snacks">Snacks</option>
      <option id="veggies">Vegetables</option>
    </select>
  </div><br><br>
  <div class="container">
    <button onClick="outputCart()">Add item to your cart</button><br><br>
    <input id="cart" type="textbox" name="output" cols="30%" row="30%">
    </input>
  </div>
  <script language="javascript">
    function outputCart() {
      var i = 0;
      var out = document.getElementsByName('products')[i].value;
      document.getElementsByName('output')[i].value = out;
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Vanilla JavaScript:

Iterate over the selected `option`s of the `select` element, store the selected options in an `array`, then display that `array` via  [**`Array.join()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```js
function outputCart() {
  var select = document.getElementsByName('products')[0];
  var options = select && select.options;
  var results = [];

  for (var i = 0, len = options.length, option; i < len; i++) {
    option = options[i];

    if (option.selected) {
      results.push(option.value || option.text);
    }
  }

  var out = document.getElementsByName('output')[0];
  out.value = results.join(', ');
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h5>Grocery Categories</h5>
  <select name="products" size="6" multiple>
    <option id="bread">Bread</option>
    <option id="dairy">Dairy</option>
    <option id="frozen">Frozen</option>
    <option id="snacks">Snacks</option>
    <option id="veggies">Vegetables</option>
  </select>
  <div class="container">
    <button onClick="outputCart()">Add item to your cart</button><br><br>
    <input id="cart" type="textbox" name="output" cols="30%" row="30%">
  </div>
</div>
```

### jQuery:

Select the `option`s, which were selected via the [**`:selected`**](https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) selector, then get the values via [**`.map`**](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) and use [**`.get`**](https://api.jquery.com/get/) to store the result as an `array`, then also `join` them:

```js
function outputCart(){
  var element = $('[name="products"]');
  var selected = element.find('option:selected');
  var result = selected
    .map(function(index, option) { return $(option).val(); })
    .get();
  
  $('#cart').val(result.join(', '));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h5>Grocery Categories</h5>
  <select name="products" size="6" multiple>
    <option id="bread">Bread</option>
    <option id="dairy">Dairy</option>
    <option id="frozen">Frozen</option>
    <option id="snacks">Snacks</option>
    <option id="veggies">Vegetables</option>
  </select>
  <div class="container">
    <button onClick="outputCart()">Add item to your cart</button><br><br>
    <input id="cart" type="textbox" name="output" cols="30%" row="30%">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler just use this, with jQuery (because you already imported it)

```js
function outputCart(){
  var arr = $("option:selected").map(function(){ return this.value }).get().join(", ");
  $('#cart').val(arr); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

       <h5>Grocery Categories</h5>
          <select name="products" size="6" multiple>
          <option id="bread">Bread</option>
          <option id="dairy">Dairy</option>
          <option id="frozen">Frozen</option>
          <option id="snacks">Snacks</option>
          <option id="veggies">Vegetables</option>
         </select>  
    
       <button onClick="outputCart()">Add item to your cart</button><br><br>
       <input id="cart" type="textbox" name="output" cols="30%" row="30%">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this change function.

```js
function outputCart(){
   var i = 0;
   var selectItems = document.getElementsByName('products')[i].selectedOptions; 
   var out = [];
   for(let options of selectItems){
  out.push(options.value);
   }
   document.getElementsByName('output')[i].value= out.join(",");
}
```